# Ant build of a J2EE project fails by giving various compilation errors and warnings

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, ant, weblogic12c

I am working on a java project for which I am using Web logic 12c server to deploy. I have written a build file which consist of init, build, compile and deploy stages. But ant build fails when it comes to compilation.I am including build file and error log.  Please tell me in respect of web logic server.Also suggest any correction in build file if any.

```
 <project name="CaptchaTest" default="build" basedir=".">
    <property name="weblogic-home" value="\C:\Oracle\Middleware\Oracle_Home\user_projects\domains\DevDomain" />
    <description>
        Build file for CaptchaTest
    </description>

    <path id="build.classpath">
      <fileset dir="WebContent/WEB-INF/lib" includes="*.jar" />
      <fileset dir="${weblogic-home}/lib" includes="*.jar" />
      <pathelement location="."/>
    </path>

    <target name="init">
        <delete dir="dist" />
        <mkdir dir="dist" />
    </target>

    <target name="build" depends="init">
        <war destfile="./dist/captchatest.war">
            <fileset dir="WebContent">
            </fileset>
        </war>
    </target>

    <target name="compile" depends="build">
        <javac includeantruntime="false" srcdir="./src/com/amgen/sharedservices/"
               destdir="./WebContent/WEB-INF/classes" classpathref="build.classpath"/>
    </target>

    <taskdef name="wldeploy" 
        classname="weblogic.ant.taskdefs.management.WLDeploy" 
        classpath="C:/Oracle/Middleware/Oracle_Home/wlserver/server/lib/weblogic.jar" />

    <target name="deploy" depends="compile">
        <wldeploy action="deploy" name="captcha" source="./dist/captchatest.war"
        user="DevDomain"
        password="" 
        verbose="true"
        adminurl="t3://localhost:7001"
        upload="true"
        targets="AdminServer" />

    </target>

    <target name="undeploy">

    </target>
</project>
```

error log

```
Buildfile: C:\Users\pandabhi\eclipseworkspace\CaptchaTest\build.xml
init:
   [delete] Deleting directory C:\Users\pandabhi\eclipseworkspace\CaptchaTest\dist
    [mkdir] Created dir: C:\Users\pandabhi\eclipseworkspace\CaptchaTest\dist
build:
      [war] Building war: C:\Users\pandabhi\eclipseworkspace\CaptchaTest\dist\captchatest.war
compile:
    [javac] Compiling 5 source files to C:\Users\pandabhi\eclipseworkspace\CaptchaTest\WebContent\WEB-INF\classes
    [javac] C:\Users\pandabhi\eclipseworkspace\CaptchaTest\src\com\amgen\sharedservices\ImageCaptchaServlet.java:19: warning: WaveFileWriter is internal proprietary API and may be removed in a future release
    [javac] import com.sun.media.sound.WaveFileWriter;
    [javac]                           ^
    [javac] C:\Users\pandabhi\eclipseworkspace\CaptchaTest\src\com\amgen\sharedservices\ImageCaptchaServlet.java:32: warning: PixelConverter is internal proprietary API and may be removed in a future release
    [javac] import sun.awt.image.PixelConverter.Bgrx;
    [javac]                     ^
    [javac] C:\Users\pandabhi\eclipseworkspace\CaptchaTest\src\com\amgen\sharedservices\ImageCaptchaServlet.java:32: warning: PixelConverter is internal proprietary API and may be removed in a future release
    [javac] import sun.awt.image.PixelConverter.Bgrx;
    [javac]                     ^
    [javac] C:\Oracle\Middleware\Oracle_Home\user_projects\domains\DevDomain\lib\hibernate-validator-5.1.3.Final.jar(org/hibernate/validator/constraints/Email.class): warning: Cannot find annotation method 'validatedBy()' in type 'Constraint': class file for javax.validation.Constraint not found
    [javac] C:\Oracle\Middleware\Oracle_Home\user_projects\domains\DevDomain\lib\hibernate-validator-5.1.3.Final.jar(org/hibernate/validator/constraints/Email.class): warning: Cannot find annotation method 'regexp()' in type 'Pattern': class file for javax.validation.constraints.Pattern not found
    [javac] C:\Oracle\Middleware\Oracle_Home\user_projects\domains\DevDomain\lib\hibernate-validator-5.1.3.Final.jar(org/hibernate/validator/constraints/Email.class): warning: Cannot find annotation method 'constraint()' in type 'OverridesAttribute': class file for javax.validation.OverridesAttribute not found
    [javac] C:\Oracle\Middleware\Oracle_Home\user_projects\domains\DevDomain\lib\hibernate-validator-5.1.3.Final.jar(org/hibernate/validator/constraints/Email.class): warning: Cannot find annotation method 'name()' in type 'OverridesAttribute'
    [javac] C:\Oracle\Middleware\Oracle_Home\user_projects\domains\DevDomain\lib\hibernate-validator-5.1.3.Final.jar(org/hibernate/validator/constraints/Email.class): warning: Cannot find annotation method 'constraint()' in type 'OverridesAttribute'
    [javac] C:\Oracle\Middleware\Oracle_Home\user_projects\domains\DevDomain\lib\hibernate-validator-5.1.3.Final.jar(org/hibernate/validator/constraints/Email.class): warning: Cannot find annotation method 'name()' in type 'OverridesAttribute'
    [javac] C:\Oracle\Middleware\Oracle_Home\user_projects\domains\DevDomain\lib\hibernate-validator-5.1.3.Final.jar(org/hibernate/validator/constraints/Length.class): warning: Cannot find annotation method 'validatedBy()' in type 'Constraint'
    [javac] C:\Oracle\Middleware\Oracle_Home\user_projects\domains\DevDomain\lib\hibernate-validator-5.1.3.Final.jar(org/hibernate/validator/constraints/ModCheck.class): warning: Cannot find annotation method 'validatedBy()' in type 'Constraint'
    [javac] C:\Oracle\Middleware\Oracle_Home\user_projects\domains\DevDomain\lib\hibernate-validator-5.1.3.Final.jar(org/hibernate/validator/constraints/LuhnCheck.class): warning: Cannot find annotation method 'validatedBy()' in type 'Constraint'
    [javac] C:\Oracle\Middleware\Oracle_Home\user_projects\domains\DevDomain\lib\hibernate-validator-5.1.3.Final.jar(org/hibernate/validator/constraints/Mod10Check.class): warning: Cannot find annotation method 'validatedBy()' in type 'Constraint'
    [javac] C:\Oracle\Middleware\Oracle_Home\user_projects\domains\DevDomain\lib\hibernate-validator-5.1.3.Final.jar(org/hibernate/validator/constraints/Mod11Check.class): warning: Cannot find annotation method 'validatedBy()' in type 'Constraint'
    [javac] C:\Oracle\Middleware\Oracle_Home\user_projects\domains\DevDomain\lib\hibernate-validator-5.1.3.Final.jar(org/hibernate/validator/constraints/NotBlank.class): warning: Cannot find annotation method 'validatedBy()' in type 'Constraint'
    [javac] C:\Oracle\Middleware\Oracle_Home\user_projects\domains\DevDomain\lib\hibernate-validator-5.1.3.Final.jar(org/hibernate/validator/constraints/SafeHtml.class): warning: Cannot find annotation method 'validatedBy()' in type 'Constraint'
    [javac] C:\Oracle\Middleware\Oracle_Home\user_projects\domains\DevDomain\lib\hibernate-validator-5.1.3.Final.jar(org/hibernate/validator/constraints/ScriptAssert.class): warning: Cannot find annotation method 'validatedBy()' in type 'Constraint'
    [javac] C:\Oracle\Middleware\Oracle_Home\user_projects\domains\DevDomain\lib\hibernate-validator-5.1.3.Final.jar(org/hibernate/validator/constraints/URL.class): warning: Cannot find annotation method 'validatedBy()' in type 'Constraint'
    [javac] C:\Oracle\Middleware\Oracle_Home\user_projects\domains\DevDomain\lib\hibernate-validator-5.1.3.Final.jar(org/hibernate/validator/constraints/URL.class): warning: Cannot find annotation method 'regexp()' in type 'Pattern'
    [javac] C:\Oracle\Middleware\Oracle_Home\user_projects\domains\DevDomain\lib\hibernate-validator-5.1.3.Final.jar(org/hibernate/validator/constraints/URL.class): warning: Cannot find annotation method 'constraint()' in type 'OverridesAttribute'
    [javac] C:\Oracle\Middleware\Oracle_Home\user_projects\domains\DevDomain\lib\hibernate-validator-5.1.3.Final.jar(org/hibernate/validator/constraints/URL.class): warning: Cannot find annotation method 'name()' in type 'OverridesAttribute'
    [javac] C:\Oracle\Middleware\Oracle_Home\user_projects\domains\DevDomain\lib\hibernate-validator-5.1.3.Final.jar(org/hibernate/validator/constraints/URL.class): warning: Cannot find annotation method 'constraint()' in type 'OverridesAttribute'
    [javac] C:\Oracle\Middleware\Oracle_Home\user_projects\domains\DevDomain\lib\hibernate-validator-5.1.3.Final.jar(org/hibernate/validator/constraints/URL.class): warning: Cannot find annotation method 'name()' in type 'OverridesAttribute'
    [javac] C:\Users\pandabhi\eclipseworkspace\CaptchaTest\src\com\amgen\sharedservices\ImageCaptchaServlet.java:19: warning: WaveFileWriter is internal proprietary API and may be removed in a future release
    [javac] import com.sun.media.sound.WaveFileWriter;
    [javac]                           ^
    [javac] C:\Users\pandabhi\eclipseworkspace\CaptchaTest\src\com\amgen\sharedservices\ImageCaptchaServlet.java:32: warning: PixelConverter is internal proprietary API and may be removed in a future release
    [javac] import sun.awt.image.PixelConverter.Bgrx;
    [javac]                     ^
    [javac] C:\Users\pandabhi\eclipseworkspace\CaptchaTest\src\com\amgen\sharedservices\ImageCaptchaServlet.java:32: warning: PixelConverter is internal proprietary API and may be removed in a future release
    [javac] import sun.awt.image.PixelConverter.Bgrx;
    [javac]                     ^
    [javac] C:\Users\pandabhi\eclipseworkspace\CaptchaTest\src\com\amgen\sharedservices\CaptchaTest.java:20: error: package com.sun.image.codec.jpeg does not exist
    [javac] import com.sun.image.codec.jpeg.ImageFormatException;
    [javac]                                ^
    [javac] C:\Users\pandabhi\eclipseworkspace\CaptchaTest\src\com\amgen\sharedservices\CaptchaTest.java:21: error: package com.sun.image.codec.jpeg does not exist
    [javac] import com.sun.image.codec.jpeg.JPEGCodec;
    [javac]                                ^
    [javac] C:\Users\pandabhi\eclipseworkspace\CaptchaTest\src\com\amgen\sharedservices\CaptchaTest.java:22: error: package com.sun.image.codec.jpeg does not exist
    [javac] import com.sun.image.codec.jpeg.JPEGImageEncoder;
    [javac]                                ^
    [javac] C:\Users\pandabhi\eclipseworkspace\CaptchaTest\src\com\amgen\sharedservices\ImageCaptchaServlet.java:17: error: package com.sun.image.codec.jpeg does not exist
    [javac] import com.sun.image.codec.jpeg.JPEGCodec;
    [javac]                                ^
    [javac] C:\Users\pandabhi\eclipseworkspace\CaptchaTest\src\com\amgen\sharedservices\ImageCaptchaServlet.java:18: error: package com.sun.image.codec.jpeg does not exist
    [javac] import com.sun.image.codec.jpeg.JPEGImageEncoder;
    [javac]                                ^
    [javac] C:\Oracle\Middleware\Oracle_Home\user_projects\domains\DevDomain\lib\hibernate-validator-5.1.3.Final.jar(org/hibernate/validator/constraints/Email.class): warning: Cannot find annotation method 'validatedBy()' in type 'Constraint': class file for javax.validation.Constraint not found
    [javac] C:\Oracle\Middleware\Oracle_Home\user_projects\domains\DevDomain\lib\hibernate-validator-5.1.3.Final.jar(org/hibernate/validator/constraints/Email.class): warning: Cannot find annotation method 'regexp()' in type 'Pattern': class file for javax.validation.constraints.Pattern not found
    [javac] C:\Oracle\Middleware\Oracle_Home\user_projects\domains\DevDomain\lib\hibernate-validator-5.1.3.Final.jar(org/hibernate/validator/constraints/Email.class): warning: Cannot find annotation method 'constraint()' in type 'OverridesAttribute': class file for javax.validation.OverridesAttribute not found
    [javac] C:\Oracle\Middleware\Oracle_Home\user_projects\domains\DevDomain\lib\hibernate-validator-5.1.3.Final.jar(org/hibernate/validator/constraints/Email.class): warning: Cannot find annotation method 'name()' in type 'OverridesAttribute'
    [javac] C:\Oracle\Middleware\Oracle_Home\user_projects\domains\DevDomain\lib\hibernate-validator-5.1.3.Final.jar(org/hibernate/validator/constraints/Email.class): warning: Cannot find annotation method 'constraint()' in type 'OverridesAttribute'
    [javac] C:\Oracle\Middleware\Oracle_Home\user_projects\domains\DevDomain\lib\hibernate-validator-5.1.3.Final.jar(org/hibernate/validator/constraints/Email.class): warning: Cannot find annotation method 'name()' in type 'OverridesAttribute'
    [javac] C:\Oracle\Middleware\Oracle_Home\user_projects\domains\DevDomain\lib\hibernate-validator-5.1.3.Final.jar(org/hibernate/validator/constraints/Length.class): warning: Cannot find annotation method 'validatedBy()' in type 'Constraint'
    [javac] C:\Oracle\Middleware\Oracle_Home\user_projects\domains\DevDomain\lib\hibernate-validator-5.1.3.Final.jar(org/hibernate/validator/constraints/ModCheck.class): warning: Cannot find annotation method 'validatedBy()' in type 'Constraint'
    [javac] C:\Oracle\Middleware\Oracle_Home\user_projects\domains\DevDomain\lib\hibernate-validator-5.1.3.Final.jar(org/hibernate/validator/constraints/LuhnCheck.class): warning: Cannot find annotation method 'validatedBy()' in type 'Constraint'
    [javac] C:\Oracle\Middleware\Oracle_Home\user_projects\domains\DevDomain\lib\hibernate-validator-5.1.3.Final.jar(org/hibernate/validator/constraints/Mod10Check.class): warning: Cannot find annotation method 'validatedBy()' in type 'Constraint'
    [javac] C:\Oracle\Middleware\Oracle_Home\user_projects\domains\DevDomain\lib\hibernate-validator-5.1.3.Final.jar(org/hibernate/validator/constraints/Mod11Check.class): warning: Cannot find annotation method 'validatedBy()' in type 'Constraint'
    [javac] C:\Oracle\Middleware\Oracle_Home\user_projects\domains\DevDomain\lib\hibernate-validator-5.1.3.Final.jar(org/hibernate/validator/constraints/NotBlank.class): warning: Cannot find annotation method 'validatedBy()' in type 'Constraint'
    [javac] C:\Oracle\Middleware\Oracle_Home\user_projects\domains\DevDomain\lib\hibernate-validator-5.1.3.Final.jar(org/hibernate/validator/constraints/SafeHtml.class): warning: Cannot find annotation method 'validatedBy()' in type 'Constraint'
    [javac] C:\Oracle\Middleware\Oracle_Home\user_projects\domains\DevDomain\lib\hibernate-validator-5.1.3.Final.jar(org/hibernate/validator/constraints/ScriptAssert.class): warning: Cannot find annotation method 'validatedBy()' in type 'Constraint'
    [javac] C:\Oracle\Middleware\Oracle_Home\user_projects\domains\DevDomain\lib\hibernate-validator-5.1.3.Final.jar(org/hibernate/validator/constraints/URL.class): warning: Cannot find annotation method 'validatedBy()' in type 'Constraint'
    [javac] C:\Oracle\Middleware\Oracle_Home\user_projects\domains\DevDomain\lib\hibernate-validator-5.1.3.Final.jar(org/hibernate/validator/constraints/URL.class): warning: Cannot find annotation method 'regexp()' in type 'Pattern'
    [javac] C:\Oracle\Middleware\Oracle_Home\user_projects\domains\DevDomain\lib\hibernate-validator-5.1.3.Final.jar(org/hibernate/validator/constraints/URL.class): warning: Cannot find annotation method 'constraint()' in type 'OverridesAttribute'
    [javac] C:\Oracle\Middleware\Oracle_Home\user_projects\domains\DevDomain\lib\hibernate-validator-5.1.3.Final.jar(org/hibernate/validator/constraints/URL.class): warning: Cannot find annotation method 'name()' in type 'OverridesAttribute'
    [javac] C:\Oracle\Middleware\Oracle_Home\user_projects\domains\DevDomain\lib\hibernate-validator-5.1.3.Final.jar(org/hibernate/validator/constraints/URL.class): warning: Cannot find annotation method 'constraint()' in type 'OverridesAttribute'
    [javac] C:\Oracle\Middleware\Oracle_Home\user_projects\domains\DevDomain\lib\hibernate-validator-5.1.3.Final.jar(org/hibernate/validator/constraints/URL.class): warning: Cannot find annotation method 'name()' in type 'OverridesAttribute'
    [javac] C:\Users\pandabhi\eclipseworkspace\CaptchaTest\src\com\amgen\sharedservices\CaptchaTest.java:20: error: package com.sun.image.codec.jpeg does not exist
    [javac] import com.sun.image.codec.jpeg.ImageFormatException;
    [javac]                                ^
    [javac] C:\Users\pandabhi\eclipseworkspace\CaptchaTest\src\com\amgen\sharedservices\CaptchaTest.java:21: error: package com.sun.image.codec.jpeg does not exist
    [javac] import com.sun.image.codec.jpeg.JPEGCodec;
    [javac]                                ^
    [javac] C:\Users\pandabhi\eclipseworkspace\CaptchaTest\src\com\amgen\sharedservices\CaptchaTest.java:22: error: package com.sun.image.codec.jpeg does not exist
    [javac] import com.sun.image.codec.jpeg.JPEGImageEncoder;
    [javac]                                ^
    [javac] C:\Users\pandabhi\eclipseworkspace\CaptchaTest\src\com\amgen\sharedservices\ImageCaptchaServlet.java:17: error: package com.sun.image.codec.jpeg does not exist
    [javac] import com.sun.image.codec.jpeg.JPEGCodec;
    [javac]                                ^
    [javac] C:\Users\pandabhi\eclipseworkspace\CaptchaTest\src\com\amgen\sharedservices\ImageCaptchaServlet.java:18: error: package com.sun.image.codec.jpeg does not exist
    [javac] import com.sun.image.codec.jpeg.JPEGImageEncoder;
    [javac]                                ^
    [javac] C:\Users\pandabhi\eclipseworkspace\CaptchaTest\src\com\amgen\sharedservices\ImageCaptchaServlet.java:19: warning: WaveFileWriter is internal proprietary API and may be removed in a future release
    [javac] import com.sun.media.sound.WaveFileWriter;
    [javac]                           ^
    [javac] C:\Users\pandabhi\eclipseworkspace\CaptchaTest\src\com\amgen\sharedservices\ImageCaptchaServlet.java:32: warning: PixelConverter is internal proprietary API and may be removed in a future release
    [javac] import sun.awt.image.PixelConverter.Bgrx;
    [javac]                     ^
    [javac] C:\Users\pandabhi\eclipseworkspace\CaptchaTest\src\com\amgen\sharedservices\ImageCaptchaServlet.java:32: warning: PixelConverter is internal proprietary API and may be removed in a future release
    [javac] import sun.awt.image.PixelConverter.Bgrx;
    [javac]                     ^
    [javac] C:\Users\pandabhi\eclipseworkspace\CaptchaTest\src\com\amgen\sharedservices\CaptchaVerifierServlet.java:45: error: cannot find symbol
    [javac]    b = CaptchaServiceInstance.getInstance().validateResponseForID( captchaId, inputChars );
    [javac]        ^
    [javac]   symbol:   variable CaptchaServiceInstance
    [javac]   location: class CaptchaVerifierServlet
    [javac] Note: C:\Users\pandabhi\eclipseworkspace\CaptchaTest\src\com\amgen\sharedservices\CustomListImageCaptchaEngine.java uses unchecked or unsafe operations.
    [javac] Note: Recompile with -Xlint:unchecked for details.
    [javac] 6 errors
    [javac] 49 warnings

BUILD FAILED
C:\Users\pandabhi\eclipseworkspace\CaptchaTest\build.xml:27: Compile failed; see the compiler error output for details.

Total time: 7 seconds
```

Comment: Have you tried to use any kind of internet search engine? One onf the most top results is [about replacing deprecated classes - com.sun.image.codec.jpeg.*](https://blog.idrsolutions.com/2012/05/replacing-the-deprecated-java-jpeg-classes-for-java-7/)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What's unclear to you? You're getting a lot of warnings about using proprietary APIs and some errors when a package has been removed (that's why they warn against using them).

Rewrite your software without using any `com.sun.*` packages.

Comment: Thanks. I am using these packages in my project so how can I proceed without including them ?

Comment: The packages don't exist. You can't proceed until you've rewritten the code to use existing packages.

Comment: Thanks for suggestion. Now its compiling successfully. :)